# I can't retrive the data from a .txt file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, text-files

I'm trying to make a simple ajax example, but i can't get it to work.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLhttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            //Code for IE6 and IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP);
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ((xmlhttp.readystate == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
                document.getElementbyId("mydiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", ajax_info.txt, "true");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

It is supposed to retrieve the data from a .txt file, but when I hit the button it doesn't work.

Here is my code in the body:

```
<div id="mydiv"><h2>Let Ajax change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change content</button>
```

Comment: Should it be `xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt", "true");` you forgot the quotes ""

Comment: i change that and still doesnt work

Comment: Also, if it is not a copy-paste error, `window.HTMLhttpRequest` should be `window.HTMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: You should enable firebug or developer tool bar on iE or Chrome to catch error. After that paste it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have several "spelling" errors in your code. Correct the following:

```
window.XMLhttpRequest  -->  window.XMLHttpRequest
xmlhttp.readystate     -->  xmlhttp.readyState
getElementbyId(...)    -->  getElementById(...)
ajax_info.txt          -->  "ajax_info.txt"
```

See, also, this **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/fQZtx/)**;

---

Your browsers developer console/toolbar can be of great help, when it comes to debugging such errors.

Comment: ok i change everything and still doesn't work
i check the console of my browser and this is the error i get
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Gordo/HTML/Ajax/ajax_info.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. 01%20Ajax%20Simple.html:24
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Comment: That is beacause of security restrictions (XMLHttpRequest should not be allowed to access files on the user's local file system). You should setup a local webserver (e.g. using **[XAMPP](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apachefriends.org%2Fen%2Fxampp.html&ei=RHa1UfPjMMGGhQeOoYHIAg&usg=AFQjCNGc5NLvRxcZrB8MRP6RiYtrUCzJBg&sig2=94nRPEcRemTGrgV-P8c7og&bvm=bv.47534661,d.ZG4)**) for testing purposes and change the URL to "http://localhost/myfiles/ajax_info.txt" (or something similar based on your setup).

Comment: thanks, i hosted in dropbox but im getting this error
     XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5zh9cxb7hb7bqi/ajax_info.txt. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Is your HTML file in the same DB folder ? In any case, consider setting up a local webserver or (if you are using PHP) try a free web-hosting plan [000webhost](http://000webhost.com) is fine (imo).

Comment: @FranciscoGilSandoval: BTW, I tried it in my Dropbox and it works fine: **[working demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12617754/SOdemo/test.html)**